# Directly Referencing Properties in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I encountered a bug in a script I wrote this morning where I wasn't getting an output from my Select-String expression. After a bit of playing I realized that this expression would not return the value of my match in v2.0 but would in v4.0 where I originally wrote it.

```
($log | Select-String "\[CIsoCreator\] Creating iso file" -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty line -Last 1 | Select-String "([A-Z]\:)(.*\\)*.*\.iso").matches.value
```

After trying a few things I ended up with this which does return as expected.

```
($log | Select-String "\[CIsoCreator\] Creating iso file" -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty line -Last 1 | Select-String "([A-Z]\:)(.*\\)*.*\.iso").matches | select -expandproperty value
```

It seems to me there are some different rules in v2.0 that govern when you can directly reference properties but I have been unable to find a mention of this.

Does anyone have some insight in how this works between versions?

Comment: See blog posting [New V3 Language Features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/) regarding member enumeration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a change in language behavior introduced in PowerShell version 3.0 - from the ["What's new in PowerShell 3.0" release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-windows-powershell-50?view=powershell-6#windows-powershell-language-enhancements):

> ## Windows PowerShell Language Enhancements
>
> Windows PowerShell 3.0 includes many features that are designed to make its language simpler,
> easier to use, and to avoid common errors. The improvements include
> ***property enumeration***, count and length properties on scalar objects,
> new redirection operators, the $Using scope modifier, PSItem automatic
> variable, flexible script formatting, attributes of variables,
> simplified attribute arguments, numeric command names, the
> Stop-Parsing operator, improved array splatting, new bit operators,
> ordered dictionaries, PSCustomObject casting, and improved
> comment-based help.

<sup>(*Emphasis added by me*)</sup>

Property enumeration allows the `.` reference operator to resolve the properties of individual members of an array expression, even though the array itself has no such property:

```
$Things = 1..3 |%{ New-Object psobject -Property @{Prop = $_} }
$Things.Prop   # Starting with version 3.0, this outputs the array 1,2,3 
               # In PowerShell version 2.0, this will throw an error 
               # because [Object[]] ($Things) has no such property
```

Comment: I read that and it didn't make sense at the time. 

I just went back and double checked and I am being returned an array with a length of 1 so this is indeed the issue.