# select string with words and numbers

Tags: powershell

Trying to select a string that returns words and numbers without erasing the rest of the output.

Right now I have the following:

```
$files = @'
  Associations : 1, 2, 3, 4
  Transactions: 20, 21, 22

  Associations : 5, 6, 7, 8
  Transactions, 99, TRANS12, TRANS13, 97
    @'

$blob = $files -split '\r?\n'
$array = @()
[bool]$transBool = $false

$blob | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match ':') {
        if ($_ -match '(Transactions)' -or $_ -match '(Tr)' -or $_ -match '(Trans)') {
            $Trans = ($_ -split ':')[-1].TrimStart(",").TrimEnd(",")
            $trans = $Trans -split ',' -replace " ", "" | select -Unique
            $transBool = $true
        } elseif ...

        if ($Trans -match '[A-Z]') {
            $transBool = $true
            $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            TransactionsAugust= $Trans

            $output = "{0}
  `Transactions for August : {1}" -f $output,
                      (($array.TransactionsAugust | Where-Object {$_ -like "[A-Z]*" -like "[0-9]" } | select -Unique) -join ",")

            Write-Host $output
```

I'm able to pull all the Transactions that include the word TRANS on my output, but its also getting rid of 99 and 97 for example.

Goal: String is able to capture TRANS12, TRANS13 and return into a category named Transactions for August. Transactions 99 and 97 will be pulled out into a different category, called into another array.

Comment: You have 3 code snippets with 3 different variables (`$files`, `$Trans`, `$output`) that don't seem to have any relation to each other. You also have a typo in your first code snippet. Please create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem you're trying to solve, then [edit] your question and copy/paste that code.

Comment: I did not want to include the whole code, it  would be a lot of code lines here

Comment: I didn't ask you to provide your *entire* code. Please read again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the variable definitions in the [answer from Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57693069/1701026)

You might simplify the matching using the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) cmdlet to retrieve the concerned values:

```
$InStuff | Select-String $TargetPattern -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```

<sub>Note: the syntax `$_.Matches.Value` (called "**property enumeration**") requires PSv3 or higher,

for PSv2 use the [`Select-Object -ExpandProperty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50118339/1701026) cmdlet parameter.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

i am not good with strictly regex solutions [*blush*] , so this uses a very simple regex pattern. if you can get a regex master to give you a complex pattern, it will likely be faster.

what the code does ...

- fakes reading in a file
  your example had several errors in it, so i used an edited version.
- sets the target pattern
  the pattern is the word `trans` and one-or-more digits.
- uses the way that `-match` works on a collection to get any line that contains the target pattern
- splits on `,` [space and then comma]
- trims away any leading/trailing whitespace
- filters for any items that contain the target pattern
- sends that to the `$TargetItems` collection
- displays the items in that collection

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
Associations : 1, 2, 3, 4
Transactions: 20, 21, 22 

Associations : 5, 6, 7, 8
Transactions, 99, TRANS12, TRANS13, 97
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$TargetPattern = 'trans\d{1,}'

$TargetItems = ($InStuff -match $TargetPattern -split ', ').
    Trim().
    Where({
        $_ -match $TargetPattern
        })

$TargetItems
```

output ...

```
TRANS12
TRANS13
```

Comment: You're making it too difficult, just: `$InStuff | Select-String  $TargetPattern -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}`

Comment: @iRon - ha! that is better - please post it as an answer so the OP will see it. [*grin*]

Comment: Done. Anyways, `+1` for the initiative and explanation.